# ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient Failed to build mysqlclient >Win10-Flask-V.S. Code<

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-mysql

I'm unable to get the 'flask run --debug'  command to work in my virtual environment in VS Code. It initially prompted me to install 'flask-mysqldb', and after running the 'pip install flask-mysqldb' command, it begins downloading until it is interrupted, giving me the following message:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

 ** × Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1**
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      # Options for building extension module:
        library_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\lib\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\lib']
        libraries: ['kernel32', 'advapi32', 'wsock32', 'shlwapi', 'Ws2_32', 'crypt32', 'secur32', 'bcrypt', 'mariadbclient']
        extra_link_args: ['/MANIFEST']
        include_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\include\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\include']
        extra_objects: []
        define_macros: [('version_info', (2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)), ('__version__', '2.2.0')]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      ...
      src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
**  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.**
```

I would like to know how to proceed. I have already tried with ChatGPT, and the solutions it suggested did not resolve this dilemma for me.

Comment: I recommend considering the use of the `pymysql` module instead of `mysqlclient`. You can find a detailed solution and explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77610994/tying-to-install-mysqlclient-in-windows-11-getting-an-error/77744606#77744606). It might prove helpful in resolving the installation issue you're facing. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

try it over and over again, till the download is complete.

Explaination:

The server stops at different times sending data and you get your error.

pip can **not resume** downloads, so that it tries to download the whole package over again.

And you need to try it till the download is completed.

Update:
There is already a discussions on github https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4796